# Compile sub-project with regular JDK, add the result to my Android App

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm trying to add a local copy of [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) into my Android App, because there seems to be a bug where interrupting a thread running a query leads to a finalizer timeout in the `JtdsStatement` class, and I'd like to debug and fix this.

The problem is, jTDS won't build with the Android SDK.  I have to build it with a regular JDK, because it uses some obscure JDK features like for instance the `org.ietf.jgss` Java package.

What certainly works is building a JAR of jTDS by compiling it outside Android Studio, then adding that JAR into my Android project.  But better would be if I could have the source code of jTDS within my project and build it all together, so I can more rapidly test changes to jTDS in my app.

So is there a way to have a sub-project in Android Studio built with regular JDK, say for instance to generate a JAR, and then add that JAR as a dependency to the main project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have figured it out.

1. Put the jTDS code into a `jtds` sub-directory under the top-level of your Android project.
2. Create a `build.gradle` within this `jtds` sub-directory:

   ```
   apply plugin: 'java-library'

   java {
       sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
       targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8

       sourceSets.main {
           java.srcDirs = ['src/main']
           resources.srcDirs = ['src/main']
       }
   }

   dependencies {
       implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'lib')
   }

   compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'

   tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
       options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
   }
   ```
3. Include the sub-project (the correct term might be "module", I'm not sure) in your top-level `settings.gradle` file:

   ```
   include ':app', ':lib1', ':lib2', ':lib3', ':jtds'
   ```
4. Add the module as a dependency to the `app` module by editing your `app/build.gradle`:

   ```
   // ...

   dependencies {
       // ...
       implementation project(':jtds')
       // ...
   }

   // ...
   ```

That's all, it works for me.

Some notes, for those who wish to understand more details:

- The original jTDS source code was encoded in the Windows-1252 charset.  I re-encoded the files to UTF-8 which is why I had to include the corresponding lines about file encoding in `jtds/build.gradle`.  I could have probably left the files in the Windows encoding and omitted those lines from `jtds/build.gradle` but I prefer to have all my source code in UTF-8.
- The `resources.srcDirs = ['src/main']` line in `jtds/build.gradle` seems to be necessary to include some `foo.properties` files that are part of the jTDS source code into the generated JAR.  Otherwise, I was getting an error message saying `no message resource found for message property prop.servertype` upon trying to connect to SQL Server.
- The jTDS sources include a number of JAR files which they depend on, hence including them via the `implementation fileTree(...)` declaration in the `dependencies` block of `jtds/build.gradle`.